# DefaultCredentials in Mono

Tags: .net, http, authentication, mono

I have a console application on Mono (2.10.6)

I'm trying to make a HttpRequest using WebRequest etc. 
The request is to SharePoint site with windows authentication. 
I pass DefaultCredentials/DefaultNetworkCredentials to it and always get HTTP 401 Unauthorized. 
Exactly the same code works on MS .NET fine.

For now the only way that worked for me is to create a NetworkCredential with specified domain, login and password. It's is not acceptable...

Is there any way to make http requests with window authentication in Mono?

Comment: Are you speaking about Mono on windows or linux ? because on linux it would need to speak to some provider of windows login information (Say samba) and submit them to the http server using the NTLM or Kerberos infos... I don't know the current status of all of that on Linux mono but don't get your hopes too high...

Comment: I'm sory, my platform is Windows =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigation shows that a credentials stuff isn't well supported in Mono, so this is no straightforward way to solve the problem except implementing it yourselves.